# Extract First Monetary Amount Using Regex

Tags: regex

I am using RPA to extract a monetary amount from a string of text. I want to catch the first monetary amount.

Regex Used:

```
(\$|EUR)\s*(\d*\.\d+)?\b
```

Sample string

```
Up to €1,000 for benefits towards specific treatment at approved centres, once per cycle, max 2 per lifetime
Treatment €1,500 per lifetime for surgery or €200 per lifetime for medical needs at approved cenrtes
```

Comment: Maybe `(?<=^(?:(?!EUR)[^$€])*?(?:[$€]|EUR)\s*)\d[\d,.]*`?

Comment: Or perhaps using an anchor `(?s)^\A.*? ((?:[$€]|EUR)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/k99VJb/1

Comment: Actually, in that case, if a capturing group can be used, `^[\s\S]*?(?:[$€]|EUR)\s*)(\d[\d,.]*)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (?) were searching "EUR" instead of "€" and "." instead of ",".

Just change your regex with:

```
[$€]\s*(\d*,?\d+)?\b
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/s2NmAl/4).

Comment: If you think it is the only problem, then please just consider casting a close vote as the question is just off-topic/typo. The real problem is that the software OP uses has the multiple matching mode on by default, and there is no way to stop it after the first match is found.